# How to evaluate all code blocks when exporting in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have an `org-mode` document with many different R source code blocks.  Whenever I hit <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> and export to PDF or HTML I get a different prompt asking to evaluate each code block.  This wasn't a big deal, but now I have to type `yes` 20+ times.  Is there an option to automatically evaluate all the code blocks?

Comment: You might want to check the variable `org-export-babel-evaluate`. If you have many blocks, you might not want to actually evaluate all of them upon export.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!  I'll accept your answer once it lets me : )

Answer (score 10):

Put the following line at the top of your file, that way you get asked one time upon opening it, and the safer non-evaluating default remains true for other files

```
# -*- org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil -*-
```

Comment: Adding to block header :eval no-export worked for me.