# Run multiple blocks in babel-execute-subtree without answering a yes

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Upon running the source code from org mode by  invoking M-x org-babel-execute-subtree

I have to respond to every code block with a 'y`

How could configure it run as default 'y'

Comment: I should have looked for duplicates of this before answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668112/how-to-evaluate-all-code-blocks-when-exporting-in-emacs-org-mode/22668200#22668200 is probably the closest one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate all code blocks when exporting in emacs org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668112/how-to-evaluate-all-code-blocks-when-exporting-in-emacs-org-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluate

```
      (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
```

If you really want to skip this step always, you have to add the above form to your initialization file.

Here's the doc string of the variable:

> Documentation:
>
> Confirm before evaluation.
>
> Require confirmation before interactively evaluating code
>   blocks in Org buffers.  The default value of this variable is t,
>   meaning confirmation is required for any code block evaluation.
>   This variable can be set to nil to inhibit any future
>   confirmation requests.  This variable can also be set to a
>   function which takes two arguments the language of the code block
>   and the body of the code block.  Such a function should then
>   return a non-nil value if the user should be prompted for
>   execution or nil if no prompt is required.
>
> Warning: Disabling confirmation may result in accidental
>   evaluation of potentially harmful code.  It may be advisable
>   remove code block execution from ‘C-c C-c’ as further protection
>   against accidental code block evaluation.  The
>   ‘org-babel-no-eval-on-ctrl-c-ctrl-c’ variable can be used to
>   remove code block execution from the ‘C-c C-c’ keybinding.
>
> You can customize this variable.

You should at least be aware of the warning.